# See Excel locking history

Tags: locking, ms-office

My question is: Is there a way to see when an excel file or an excel file's sheet were first locked and/or last locked. Something like the Last Modified field.

We are working with a bunch of excel files and I need to know since when certain values in them cannot be changed without the required password.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using something like Dropbox or other document handling system, you probably won't have the capability of using versions. You could activate Track Changes going forward in the Excel file to see exactly what users are changing what on the spreadsheet, but that's as far as the functionality goes.